# Eigenstates of Fourier transformation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, schwartz-distributions, fourier-transform

Let $\gamma$ be defined on $\mathbb R^n$ by $\gamma (x)=e^{-π x^2}$. With $\mathcal F$ standing for the Fourier transformation defined on the Schwartz space by
$$
(\mathcal F u)(\xi)=\int e^{-2iπ x\cdot \xi} u(x) dx,
$$
we have 
$
\mathcal F\gamma =\gamma.
$
We can also define $\mathcal F$ for the tempered distribution ($\mathscr S'$)
with the duality formula
$$
\langle \widehat T,\phi\rangle_{\mathscr S',\mathscr S}=\langle T,\widehat{\phi}\rangle_{\mathscr S',\mathscr S}.
$$
For instance, the Poisson summation formula is $\widehat S=S$ with 
$S=\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z^n}\delta_k$. Finally the question:
determine all the tempered distributions $T$ such that
$$
\mathcal F T=T.
$$

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12045/what-are-fixed-points-of-the-fourier-transform

Comment: The question is not Hilbertian, but on $\mathcal S'$: I want also to include the Poisson summation formula.

Comment: I don't see why this makes any difference. Voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: A tempered distribution satisfies $T=\hat T$ iff $\langle T,\hat\phi-\phi\rangle=0$ for all Schwartz functions $\phi$. If the Schwartz space is decomposed into eigenspaces of the Fourier transform as $E_1\oplus E_{-1}\oplus E_i\oplus E_{-i}$, then tempered distributions with eigenvalue one correspond to the dual space of $E_1$ (by extension by zero to the Schwartz space).

Comment: That is, you want all the tempered distributions that annihilate $E_{-1}$, $E_i$, and $E_{-i}$, and equivalently the test functions $H_j(x) \exp(-x^2/2)$ for $j \not\equiv 0 \mod 4$ where $H_j$ are the Hermite polynomials.

Comment: @Bazin: I understand, but I still thought the linked question was worth pointing out.

Comment: @Robert Israel: yes, but I would like a somewhat more explicit description yielding in particular the Poisson summation formula. The latter formula is not exactly a triviality and to provide an algebraic proof would be interesting.

Comment: @Christian Remling: yes, of course, thanks.

Comment: A bit more explicit:  $T = X + \mathcal F(X) + \mathcal F^2(X) + \mathcal F^3(X)$ for some tempered distribution $X$.  Note that $\mathcal F^2$ is the reflection $\mathcal F^2 T(x) = T(-x)$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are fixed points of the Fourier Transform](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12045/what-are-fixed-points-of-the-fourier-transform)

Answer (score 4):

In case the specific distribution-theoretic argument is not clear... as it hadn't really been overtly mentioned in comments or answers, and is not really suggested by the classical argument as in Titchmarsh and such:

E.g., for Poisson summation on $\mathbb R$: observe that the distribution "sum over integers" is annihilated by multiplication by $e^{2\pi ix}-1$, and is translation invariant. Observe that these two conditions are interchanged by Fourier transform. Show that the space of such distributions is one-dimensional: the multiplication annihilation shows that any such distribution is of order $0$ and supported at integers. By classification of distributions supported at a point, it is a sum of Dirac deltas at integers. By translation-invariance, it is (a scalar multiple of) sum-over-evaluation-at-integers. A just-slightly-more-complicated version applies in $n$-dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

This question is addressed in great detail in the book of Titchmarsh, Introduction to the theory of Fourier integrals. Such functions are called self-reciprocal, and there is a separate chapter about them. Of course Titchmarsh did not use the language of
distributions, but it is easy to translate. A recent paper on the related subject is http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.2427.