# Computing $\prod_p(\frac{p^2-1}{p^2+1})$ without the zeta function?

Tags: nt.number-theory

We see that $$\frac{2}{5}=\frac{36}{90}=\frac{6^2}{90}=\frac{\zeta(4)}{\zeta(2)^2}=\prod_p\frac{(1-\frac{1}{p^2})^2}{(1-\frac{1}{p^4})}=\prod_p \left(\frac{(p^2-1)^2}{(p^2+1)(p^2-1)}\right)=\prod_p\left(\frac{p^2-1}{p^2+1}\right)$$

$$\implies \prod_p \left(\frac{p^2-1}{p^2+1}\right)=\frac{2}{5},$$

But is this the only way to compute this infinite product over primes? It seems like such a simple product, one that could be calculated without the zeta function.

Note that $\prod_p(\frac{p^2-1}{p^2+1})$ also admits the factorization $\prod_p(\frac{p-1}{p-i})\prod_p(\frac{p+1}{p+i})$. Also notice that numerically it is quite obvious that the product is convergent to $\frac{2}{5}$: $\prod_p(\frac{p^2-1}{p^2+1})=\frac{3}{5} \cdot \frac{8}{10} \cdot \frac{24}{26} \cdot \frac{48}{50} \cdots$.

Comment: The result is attributed to Ramanujan (1913-1914), who may have used other methods (like hypergeometric series, continued fractions etc.). A reference is Le Lionnais, F. Les nombres remarquables. Paris: Hermann, p. 46, 1983.

Comment: The product seems "simple" only because the expression was rigged to remove the powers of $\pi$ in $\zeta(2)$ and $\zeta(4)$. Also, your factorization with terms $(p-1)/(p\pm i)$ is into two products that are each divergent, though that wouldn't stop Ramanujan.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I found a proof of 
$$5 \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^4} = 2 \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \right)^2$$
by rearranging sums and [wrote it up](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~speyer/ZetaFun2.pdf). The argument is just 1.5 pages, the other 4.5 are explanations and context.

Here is a summary using divergent sums; see the write up for a correct version. Set
$$h(m,n) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{m^3 (n-m)} & m \neq n,\ m \neq 0, \\
0 & m=n \ \text{or} \ m=0.
\end{cases}$$
Then we should have
$$\sum_{(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z}^2} h(m,n) - h(n,2n-m) =0$$
as every value occurs twice with opposite signs. So $\sum_{(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z}^2} g(m,n)=0$ where
$$g(m,n) :=  h(m,n) - h(n,2n-m) =   \begin{cases}
\frac{m^2+mn+n^2}{m^3 n^3} & m \neq n,\ m, n \neq 0 \\
- \frac{1}{m^4} & n=0,\ m \neq 0 \\
- \frac{1}{n^4} & m=0,\ n \neq 0 \\
0 & m=n \end{cases}$$
Group together the terms where $(|m|, |n|)$ have a common value; we get $\sum_{(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0 }^2} f(m,n) =0$ where
$$f(m,n) = \begin{cases} 
\frac{4}{m^2 n^2} & m \neq n,\ m,n >0, \\
- \frac{2}{m^4} & m>n=0, \\
- \frac{2}{n^4} & n>m=0, \\
- \frac{2}{m^4} & m=n>0, \\
0 & m=n=0.
 \end{cases} $$
Writing this out, $4\zeta(2)^2 - 6 \zeta(4) - 4 \zeta(4)=0$, as desired.

Has anyone seen this? If this is new, I'm thinking of sending it to the *Monthly*.

Comment: @ David Speyer: No, I haven't seen it. It seems slightly related to the comment by i707107 on my answer to the MO question"What are the connections between pi and prime to numbers " just over a year ago, though that comment does not evaluate the product independently as far as I can see. It would be ineteresting to know if your method generalizes to an elementary proof that $\zeta(2m)^{n}/\zeta(2n)^{m}$ is always rational.

Comment: It would be interesting to change the summation index set and see how the constants change.  If  both sums are over primes, what multiplicative constants do you need?

Comment: Re. your write-up (which I have only scanned very quickly): Your "dropping the mask" section (especially the parenthetical remark) is excellent. It would be good if more papers included such an explanation of where reasoning has come from.

Comment: I think you should totally send your write-up to the Monthly!

Comment: I agree with Greg's encouragement and suggest also sending a copy to Richard Guy at the same time (if you haven't already emailed him).

Comment: @DavidSpeyer : I edited your punctuation a bit and I think you should do the same in the pdf document that you link to.

Comment: I only saw this now - isn't it the case that this argument is very close to one of the one proving the same in the paper of Zagier on values of zetas (http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/scanned/ValuesofZetaFunsAndApplications/fulltext.pdf), I mean second half of page 498.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko Yes it is. That's why I didn't wind up sending this anywhere. See testcase's answer below.

Comment: Ihara Kaneko zagier double shuffle relation?

Answer (score 41):

A proof of this identity not using properties of the Riemann zeta function is listed as an unsolved problem in section B48 of Guy's *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory*.

An amusing observation: this identity *implies* the infinitude of primes. If the product over $p$ were finite, the final answer would be a rational number with a factor of $3$ in its numerator --- the very first term in the product has a $3$ in the numerator, and $3$ cannot divide $u^2+1$ for any integer $u$, so the $3$ can never cancel.

Answer (score 33):

An elementary proof of the identity
$$ 2 \zeta(2)^2 = 5\zeta(4)$$
has been found by Don Zagier in the paper

http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/tex/ConsequencesCohomologySL/fulltext.pdf

The idea seems similar to how David Speyer proves it in that he starts by defining the function

$$ f(m,n) = \frac{2}{n^3m} + \frac{1}{n^2m^2} + \frac{2}{nm^3} $$
and then verifies that 
$$  f(m,n) -f(m,n+m) - f(m+n,n)  = \frac{2}{m^2n^2}.$$

But since we also have 
$$   \sum_{n,m>0} f(m,n)  - \sum_{n,m>0} f(m,n+m) - \sum_{m,n>0} f(m+n,n) = \sum_{n>0} f(n,n),$$
since only the diagonal terms survive, this gives the identity 
$$ 2 \zeta(2)^2 = 5\zeta(4).$$

The crucial function $f(m,n)$ seems to be part of a larger family of functions with ties to period polynomials, as explained in the paper.

Comment: The actual reference being "Quelques conséquences surprenantes de la cohomologie de SL2(Z)" in Leçons de Mathématiques d'aujourd'hui, Vol. 1,Cassini, Paris (2000). 99-123.  An earlier paper by Zagier also mentionning this is "Values of zeta functions and their applications", in First European Congress of Mathematics, Volume II, Progress in Math. 120, Birkhäuser-Verlag, Basel, (1994) 497-512, http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/scanned/ValuesofZetaFunsAndApplications/fulltext.pdf

Comment: Thanks, this is really interesting. It looks like Zagier returned to this again in "PERIODS OF MODULAR FORMS, TRACES OF HECKE OPERATORS, AND MULTIPLE ZETA VALUES" http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/kokyuroku/843/fulltext.pdf and he cites an article of Skoruppa http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X83710073 which proves identities between Eisenstein series in a similar manner. On a quick glance, it looks to me like Zagier is using Taylor series of elliptic functions where I am using Taylor series of trig functions. But I need to read more closely.

Answer (score 8):

I would guess that every introductory paper about polynomial relations of multiple zeta values (from Kontsevich-Manin to F. Brown) explains this identity in an elementary manner. But I have no precise reference to offer now, except for [E. Panzer's notes](http://www2.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~mzv/mzv2013.pdf) (see the formula on top of page 4).