# How do i show that:$\prod\frac{p^2+1}{p^2-1}=\frac{5}{2}$ without using properties of Riemann zeta function?

Tags: prime-numbers, divisors, euler-product

In order to know more about  product  over primes  ,I would like to know how do I show that :$$\prod\frac{p^2+1}{p^2-1}=\frac{5}{2}$$ without using properties of Riemann zeta function ?

**Note01** : it is well known that $$\prod\frac{p^2+1}{p^2-1}=\frac{{\zeta}^2(2)}{\zeta(4)}=\frac{5}{2}$$ but is there other method to show that ?

**Note 02** :I  wish using divisor function properties

Thank you for any help

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/164092

Comment: @nice proof ,thank you for your help

Comment: @PaceNielsen,in  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/164092 used Riemann zeta function properties , but i seek to use other properties as example :power sum divisor function ,all method which are different from zeta function properties uses !!!

Comment: @zeraouliarafik I don't see any use of properties of the zeta function, unless you count using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic to get the Euler product.  Are you seeing something else?

Comment: This is probably nonsense but:  If you formally expand the factors of this product as power series in $p$, use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, and make the heroic assumption that the product of infinitely many $-1$'s is $+1$, then the expression becomes $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{\Omega(n)}n^2 = 5/2$, where $\Omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors in $n$.  I wonder if this could be true in some sense. For example, set $Z(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{\Omega(n)}n^{-s}$ where this converges, and analytically continue.  Then we could hope that $Z(-2)=5/2$. Could this be?

Comment: but by your way you must check the properties of zeta function however you are used the F.T of arithmetic !!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a well-known problem, attributed to Sam Wagstaff in Richard Guy's *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory*.  Section B48 "Products taken over primes" includes a paragraph

> Wagstaff asked for an elementary proof (e.g., without using properties of the Riemann zeta-function that $$\prod_p \frac{p^2+1}{p^2-1} = \frac52 $$
>   where the product is taken over all primes. It seems very unlikely that there is a proof which doesn't involve analytical methods. At first glance it might appear that the fractions might cancel, but none of the numerators
>   are divisible by 3 [. . .]

with a reference to

> David Borwein & Jonathan M. Borwein, On an intriguing integral and some series related to $\zeta(4)$, *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.*, **123** (1995) 1191-1198; *MR* **95e**:11137.

Comment: oh, sorry for this

Comment: @zeraouliarafik, don't worry, in some sense this was a perfectly-answerable question for this site: it is certainly true that standard methods give the result, but asking to avoid analytic methods is a potentially interesting question about the combinatorics of cancellation/telescoping. Noam E. happened to recall at least the one prior occurrence, etc. Bingo. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett, ok thank you very much , i will do an attempt to solve it

Comment: @zeraouliarafik, but, of course, this might be very difficult, or in some sense impossible! :)

Comment: amazing, that the 3 cannot get cancelled in a elementary manner. What do you make of that?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as has been noted several times in comments, this has come up before, with a beautiful answer by David Speyer: [Computing $\prod_p(\frac{p^2-1}{p^2+1})$ without the zeta function?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164092/computing-prod-p-fracp2-1p21-without-the-zeta-function/168650#168650)

It seems to me this should put the present question to rest. The only "property" of the Riemann zeta function used is the Euler expansion $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac1{n^s} = \prod_p \frac1{1 - p^{-s}}$, but the proof of this boils down to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, which goes back to Euclid's Elements I think, so I'd hardly call this using (analytic) properties of the zeta function. Aside from that, David's demonstration (which is elementary in the technical sense) does the rest.

Comment: See the comment thread for **David Speyer**'s answer: he refrained from sending it in to the *Monthly* because a very similar argument for $\zeta(4) = (2/5) \zeta(2)^2$ had already been given by Zagier.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Thanks; I did eventually see it but had no opportunity to edit until now.